# docx.Document PackageNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-docx

I received a ipython notebook file with the following code and I'm attempting to execute it via Jupyter.

```
import docx;
from django.utils.encoding import smart_text;
doc = docx.Document('test_file.docx')
```

I get the following traceback

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PackageNotFoundError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-2ff3b55810a7> in <module>()
      1 import docx;
      2 from django.utils.encoding import smart_text;
----> 3 doc = docx.Document('test_file.docx')
      4 statements = [para.text.strip() for para in doc.paragraphs
      5               if para.text.strip() != '']

C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\docx\api.pyc in Document(docx)
     23     """
     24     docx = _default_docx_path() if docx is None else docx
---> 25     document_part = Package.open(docx).main_document_part
     26     if document_part.content_type != CT.WML_DOCUMENT_MAIN:
     27         tmpl = "file '%s' is not a Word file, content type is '%s'"

C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\docx\opc\package.pyc in open(cls, pkg_file)
    114         *pkg_file*.
    115         """
--> 116         pkg_reader = PackageReader.from_file(pkg_file)
    117         package = cls()
    118         Unmarshaller.unmarshal(pkg_reader, package, PartFactory)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\docx\opc\pkgreader.pyc in from_file(pkg_file)
     30         Return a |PackageReader| instance loaded with contents of *pkg_file*.
     31         """
---> 32         phys_reader = PhysPkgReader(pkg_file)
     33         content_types = _ContentTypeMap.from_xml(phys_reader.content_types_xml)
     34         pkg_srels = PackageReader._srels_for(phys_reader, PACKAGE_URI)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\docx\opc\phys_pkg.pyc in __new__(cls, pkg_file)
     29             else:
     30                 raise PackageNotFoundError(
---> 31                     "Package not found at '%s'" % pkg_file
     32                 )
     33         else:  # assume it's a stream and pass it to Zip reader to sort out

PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at 'test_file.docx'
```

I uninstalled `docx` and reinstalled `python-docx` recently and wondering if that's related, or is this a separate issue?

Answer (score 1):

This means that the specified file (`'test_file.docx'`) does not exist or is not a Word document.

Check that the path is correct and that you can open the document with Word (or LibreOffice or whatever).

You might be missing a path part of the filename. Sometimes it's tricky to know what Python considers the default directory, which is where it goes looking for a filename without a path.

Comment: Seems like the docx file became corrupted at some point. Thanks.